# How to use for loop for single entity in input xml file

Tags: java, xml, web-services

I have to insert for loop in a input xml file but eclipse gives an eroor

```
+ "<FolderName></FolderName>" 
+"<RootFolderPath>" + Helper.cabinetName + "/ABC/"+odfolder+"/";
for(int $i=5;$i<FilepathArr.length;$i++)
+subproduct[$i]+
"</RootFolderPath>" 
+ "<DocumentName>" + fname[0] + "</DocumentName>"
```

the operator +is  deifned for argument type string.

Comment: What is the error message eclipse gives?

Comment: Hi @chirag, please format the code and it is missing parts from it, thanks.

Comment: You seem to be constructing XML using string operations. This is risky because XML has a lot of rules, and it is easy to generate a badly-formed XML document. It would be safer to construct your XML outputs using the XML libraries provided with your language.